# Check if `INSERT SELECT` actually inserted rows

Tags: php, mysql, sql, propel

I'm trying to insert some rows in a table using `INSERT SELECT` using PROPEL ORM. I'm trying to populate the table incrementally until all rows are copied.

```
$con = Propel::getConnection();
$sql = "INSERT INTO tmp_orders (id, name)
        SELECT  oo.id, oo.slip
        FROM   original_orders oo
            LEFT JOIN tmp_orders tmp ON oo.id=tmp.id
        WHERE tmp.id IS NULL
        LIMIT 10"  ;

        $stmt = $con->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute();
```

Ideally I want to run this script in a loop until all records are copied. I want to stop the loop once there are no more records to insert.

My initial solution is to issue 2 queries. First to select from `original_orders` to check if no more data is returned by the select then do the `INSERT SELECT` in another query.
The problem is the query is too slow, so I want to avoid doing the same select twice just to see if there is more data to insert.

Is there a way to get if the `INSERT SELECT` actually inserted anything? I tried `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();` after running the `INSERT SELECT`, but it always returns `0`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since Propel uses PDO as an abstraction layer, you could use [PDOStatement::rowCount](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php).

In your case this would be done as follows:

```
$stmt->rowCount();
```

Comment: and for PROPEL? which is my question actually.

Comment: Doesn't PROPEL make use of PDO?

Comment: yup, but I don't have access to the PDO object to call `rowCount` unless of course I'm missing something.

Comment: $stmt is the PDOResult, can't you call it on that like "$stmt->rowCount()"?

Comment: gonna give it a try just for you ;)

Comment: It worked, add your comment to your answer and I'll accept it and remove the down-vote.